# How to restart an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have created an activity. I made the launch mode as singleTask in manifest file. I donot want multiple instance of the same activity should start. I am lunching this activity on button click of another activity.

If i click the button more than once then as i have made the activity as single task then If the activity already running then nothing happens. But I want to relaunch the activity without creating another instance. How to achieve this.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: What about calling `finish()` and starting an activity with intent?

Comment: Hi Ernazm, I can check for the activity and if finish it again restart it which is not accurate solution also it gives page transition effect one step more. It should show as if an activity is started.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what is the purpose of restarting activity when it is already running?

Comment: If you are restarting the Activity just to execute the code in its `onCreate` method, then you can also do so by putting that code in [`onResume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
But I want to relaunch the activity without creating another instance
```

What you meant my relaunch without creating. I think you may have set of code that you have placed in your `onCreate` and you want to run when the activity again got control. If so its better for you to place that code to your `onResume` or `onNewIntent`. Because onCreate of the single task will only execute once

[singleTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)
*The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.*